# Problema com o Isotope e o loadmore

Tags: jquery

Eu customizei um scritp de isotope com a função de "loadmre".

Está funcionando corretamente, mas, ao clicar em qualquer um dos filtros, a classe "hidden" é removida e fica um "buraco" no rodapé.

Eu tentei mudar no Jquery a instrução para adicionar a classe, mas não consegui.
Se clicar em "banheiros", por exemplo, é possível ver o que ocorre.

Código no [Codepen](https://codepen.io/roger2p/pen/KbqPOq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione à classe `.isotope` a propriedade abaixo:

```
.isotope{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Isso irá restringir a área da div apenas aos elementos visíveis.